# add sqlite database to setup wizard

Tags: c#, sqlite, installation, wizard

I'm trying to create a setup for my windows application in VS 2010 which is in c#. my application use sqlite database. when I create a setup project ,after installing program, application can't connect to database. the whole folders of my program(like debug and bin folder which my database were there) don't copy at all.

after that I tried setup wizard and included all the files and folders. again it Errors like this(although system.data.sqlite is one of the dependencies in setup)   :

(System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.77.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.77.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139')

thank you for your help;)

Answer (score 0):

Other than System.Data.SQLite assembly, are there x86 and x64 SQLite subfolders present? As you may know, System.Data.SQLite is only a wrapper to unmanaged dlls; they have to be deployed with your files.